# NotSupportedException on WaitHandle.WaitAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to execute the following code. The code tries to parallely download and save images. I pass a list of images to be downloaded. I wrote this in C# 3.0 and compiled it using .NET Framework 4 (VS.NET express edition). The WaitAll operation is resulting in a **NotSupportedException (WaitAlll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported)** everytime I try to run my program. I tried removing `SetMaxThreads`, but that didn't do any difference.

```
public static void SpawnThreads(List<string> imageList){
    imageList = new List<string>(imageList);
    ManualResetEvent[] doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[imageList.Count];
    PicDownloader[] picDownloaders = new PicDownloader[imageList.Count];
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxThreadCount, MaxThreadCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++) {
        doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        PicDownloader p = new PicDownloader(imageList[i], doneEvents[i]);
        picDownloaders[i] = p;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(p.DoAction);
    }
    // The following line is resulting in "NotSupportedException"     
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
    Console.WriteLine("All pics downloaded");
}
```

Can you please let me understand what is the issue I am running into?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mark one of the methods with `[STAThread]` attribute?

Comment: Thanks Danny! The main application thread is indeed marked as [STAThread]. I removed it and works like magic. Why does VS.NET defaults all the entry methods to [STAThread]?

Comment: @Ravi: I don't think this attribute will be marked to `main` by default. Maybe it was marked by yourself?

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but In VS2012 Express for Desktop - I created a brand new application from scratch and indeed in Program.cs file, Main is decorated with the STAThread attribute.  I removed it and now it works for me.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7):

I advise against using multiple `WaitHandle` instances to wait for completion. Use the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) class instead. It results in more elegant and scalable code. Plus, the `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method only supports up to 64 handles and cannot be called on an STA thread. By refactoring your code to use the canonical pattern I came up with this.

```
public static void SpawnThreads(List<string> imageList)
{ 
  imageList = new List<string>(imageList); 
  var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
  var picDownloaders = new PicDownloader[imageList.Count]; 
  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxThreadCount, MaxThreadCount); 
  for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++) 
  { 
    finished.AddCount();    
    PicDownloader p = new PicDownloader(imageList[i]); 
    picDownloaders[i] = p; 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
      (state) =>
      {
        try
        {
          p.DoAction
        }
        finally
        {
          finished.Signal();
        }
      });
  } 
  finished.Signal();
  finished.Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("All pics downloaded"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the apartment state for the thread?

```
thread.SetApartmentState (System.Threading.Apartmentstate.MTA );
```

Comment: Thank you, But I am just creating a ThreadPool, not individual threads! ThreadPool does not allow me to set the ApartmentState.