# WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

1. Why do I get this error message? "WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported."
2. Should I use [MTAThreadAttribute] attribut? **Update:** Dosn't work with WPF applications!

Note:
 It error is at line WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
 I'm using a standard **WPF project**.

```
private void Search()
{
    const int CPUs = 2;
    var doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[CPUs];

    // Configure and launch threads using ThreadPool:
    for (int i = 0; i < CPUs; i++)
    {
        doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var f = new Indexer(Paths[i], doneEvents[i]);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f.WaitCallBack, i);
    }

    // Wait for all threads in pool 
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
    Debug.WriteLine("Search completed!");
}
```

**Update:** The following solution doesn’t work for WPF applications!
It is not possible to change the main application attribute to MTAThreadAttribute. It will result in the following error:

**Error:** "WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported."

Comment: You realize that you app will freeze completely until those Indexers are done?

Comment: Yes! I know that. But as it is it doesn’t run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784510/notsupportedexception-on-waithandle-waitall

Comment: The same error but the solution doesn't for WPF applications! You can’t change main method attribute for WPF application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about using the Tasks to do your threading for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());
var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

Comment: It's .NET Framework 4. So I have to upgrade the project. It's seems to be a better approach thought!

Comment: `Task.Run(()=>DoSomeWork())` is a better alternative

Answer (score 58):

Actually I use the following to replace WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);

```
foreach (var e in doneEvents)
    e.WaitOne();
```

Comment: are there any downsides to using this alternative?

Comment: I've seen none, but I would recommend using Task for brand new code

Comment: Tasks cannot be used for e. g. a graceful shutdown implementation, which is why I favor the answer of Brian Gideon below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194938/2477582) that recommends using a CountdownEvent

Comment: If this is so simple why did Microsoft not implement it in WaitAll() ?? After reading all answers I still don't understand the stupid error message. Why does Microsoft tell us that it does not work with STA threads? What has the type of thead to do with waiting for an event at all?

Answer (score 12):

Use one `ManualResetEvent` and wait on it. Also maintain a TaskCount variable that is set to the number of worker threads you start, use `Interlocked.Decrement` in the worker thread code as the very last action of the worker and signal the event if the counter reaches zero,e.g.

```
// other worker actions...
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref taskCount) == 0)
   doneEvent.Set();
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be the only solution since WaitAll(..) doesn’t work.

Comment: Yep, that would work. Just make sure to treat the main thread as if it were a work item and initialize `taskCount = 1` and do the `Decrement` and `Set` at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: This is very similar to using the CountdownEvent. But the CountdownEvent has the advantage that you need only one variable instead of two like in your solution.

Answer (score 10):

I would refactor your code to use the `CountdownEvent` class instead.

```
private void Search() 
{ 
    const int CPUs = 2; 
    var done = new CountdownEvent(1);

    // Configure and launch threads using ThreadPool: 
    for (int i = 0; i < CPUs; i++) 
    { 
        done.AddCount();
        var f = new Indexer(Paths[i], doneEvents[i]); 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
          (state) =>
          {
            try
            {
              f.WaitCallBack(state);
            }
            finally
            {
              done.Signal();
            }
          }, i); 
    } 

    // Wait for all threads in pool  
    done.Signal();
    done.Wait();
    Debug.WriteLine("Search completed!"); 
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect replacement for `WaitHandle.WaitAll(multipleEvents);`!

Answer (score 1):

use something like this:

```
foreach (ITask Task in Tasks)
{
    Task.WaitHandle = CompletedEvent;
    new Thread(Task.Run).Start();
}

int TasksCount = Tasks.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < TasksCount; i++)
    CompletedEvent.WaitOne();

if (AllCompleted != null)
    AllCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: -1 While cleaner, for me this is not sufficiently different to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4194938/11635