# Multithreading C# GUI ping example

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface

I want to create a multithreaded ping application where I can click on start, create `n` threads to ping multiple host at the same time, get the results from the threads in the GUI and cancel all the threads if the user clicks on the cancel button.

I have seen (a lot) of multithreading ways to do that but I want to have a code example.

Does someone know where I can find that?

Comment: I tried with Background worker but without success...

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating multiple threads, this example uses only 2 threads. One for sending ICMP packets and one for receiving the replies. You can ping thousands of machines in a few seconds.

```
//from 1.2.3.1 to  1.2.3.254
var hosts = StackOverflow.Pinger.PingAll("1.2.3.1-254");

 //from 1.2.3.1 to  1.2.3.254 and   from 1.2.5.1 to  1.2.5.254
var hosts = StackOverflow.Pinger.PingAll("1.2.3,5.1-254");
```

You can also use `async/await` not to block the UI thread

```
var hosts = await StackOverflow.Pinger.PingAllAsync(.......);
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public static class Pinger
    {
        static byte ICMP_ECHO = 8;
        static byte ICMP_ECHOREPLY = 0;
        static int OFFSET_ID = 4;
        static int OFFSET_CHECKSUM = 2;
        static int IP_HEADER_LEN = 20;
        static int ICMP_HEADER_LEN = 8;


        /**************************************************************
         *  Example Usages:
         *  
         *  PingAll("1.2.3.4")       => 1.2.3.4
         *  PingAll("1.2.3.1-255")   => 1.2.3.X
         *  PingAll("1.2.3,7.1-255") => 1.2.3.X and 1.2.7.X
         *  PingAll("1.2.3-5.1-255") => 1.2.3.X and 1.2.4.X and 1.2.5.X
         **************************************************************/
        public static IEnumerable<Host> PingAll(string subNets, int timeOut = 1500)
        {
            ushort PACKET_ID = (ushort)new Random().Next(0, ushort.MaxValue);

            //Init
            Socket rawSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
            rawSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));

            rawSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.IpTimeToLive, 255);
            rawSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, Int32.MaxValue);
            rawSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, Int32.MaxValue);
            rawSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ExclusiveAddressUse, false);

            HashSet<Host> aliveIPs = new HashSet<Host>();

            //** Receiver **
            Task receiver = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                byte[] bytesRecv = new byte[0x10000];
                EndPoint remoteAddr = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        rawSock.ReceiveFrom(bytesRecv, ref remoteAddr);
                    }
                    catch { return; };

                    ushort replyId = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytesRecv, IP_HEADER_LEN + OFFSET_ID);
                    if (bytesRecv[IP_HEADER_LEN] == ICMP_ECHOREPLY && replyId == PACKET_ID)
                    {
                        long ticksInPong = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytesRecv, IP_HEADER_LEN + ICMP_HEADER_LEN);
                        int duration = (int)((DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticksInPong) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
                        var host = new Host(((IPEndPoint)remoteAddr).Address.ToString(), duration);

                        //Console.WriteLine(host.IP + "\t:\t" + host.Duration);

                        lock (aliveIPs)
                        {
                            aliveIPs.Add(host);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Task.Yield(); //Give a chance to listener task to start.

            //** Sender **
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)//Send Ping packets twice
            {
                foreach (var ip in GetIPAddresses(subNets))
                {
                    byte[] packet = CreatePacket(PACKET_ID, BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks));
                    IPEndPoint dest = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 0);
                    try
                    {
                        rawSock.SendTo(packet, dest);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n==>" + ip);
                    }
                }
                Task.Delay(timeOut / 3).Wait();
            }

            Task.WaitAny(receiver, Task.Delay(timeOut));

            rawSock.Close();

            return aliveIPs;
        }

        public static Task<IEnumerable<Host>> PingAllAsync(string subNets, int TimeOut = 1500)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => PingAll(subNets, TimeOut));
        }

        static byte[] CreatePacket(ushort id, byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] packet = new byte[ICMP_HEADER_LEN + data.Length];
            packet[0] = ICMP_ECHO;

            Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(id), 0, packet, OFFSET_ID, 2); //copy id
            Array.Copy(data, 0, packet, ICMP_HEADER_LEN, data.Length); //copy data

            Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(GetChecksum(packet)), 0, packet, OFFSET_CHECKSUM, 2); //copy checksum

            return packet;
        }


        static ushort GetChecksum(byte[] bytes)
        {
            ulong sum = 0;
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                sum += BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, i);
            }
            if (i != bytes.Length)
                sum += bytes[i];

            sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
            sum += (sum >> 16);
            return (ushort)(~sum);
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> GetIPAddresses(string ip)
        {
            string[] parts = ip.Split('.');
            if (parts.Length != 4) throw new FormatException("Invalid format");
            return
                from p1 in GetRange(parts[0])
                from p2 in GetRange(parts[1])
                from p3 in GetRange(parts[2])
                from p4 in GetRange(parts[3])
                select String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", p1, p2, p3, p4);
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> GetRange(string s)
        {
            foreach (var part in s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                var range = part.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (range.Length > 2) throw new FormatException(String.Format("Invalid Format \"{0}\"", range));
                if (range.Length == 1) yield return int.Parse(range[0]);
                else
                {
                    for (int i = int.Parse(range[0]); i <= int.Parse(range[1]); i++)
                    {
                        yield return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class Host
        {
            public string IP { get; private set; }
            public int Duration { get; private set; }

            public Host(string IP, int duration)
            {
                this.IP = IP;
                this.Duration = duration;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                return IP.Equals((obj as Host).IP);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return IP.GetHashCode();
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return IP;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop the thread or have updates when started ? I ping devices on GPRS network. The first packet is usually lost and average ping is around 2500 ms... Thanks !

Comment: @si2w above code send two ICMP packets to each machine. It also has a timeout parameter.